# Is it Ok to generate a random URL-based-key instead of user/pass in a one-time use web application?

Tags: security, web-applications, authentication, passwords

Lets say we have an web application that client accesses our app.
He works on our app for a few hours/days and never comes back! And in this app client could send/receive sensitive information.

Even though username/password could be good, we all know that passwords sucks, because our mind is not a good random generator, it can't save random data, and clients are lazy to use a good password, Also a normal 8 ascii character password is only 32 bit, only if we really choose that 8 characters randomly! (like following ASCII characters which never happens: \34\86\121\8\43\0\8\27)

So, we are thinking of generating a 256bit random value from /dev/urandom, and send it via email. This way, we have a really long and good random key instead of a short, and (almost) guessable password.

This way, the only way to break system is to access client email (which if attacker can access client email, can use our password reset tool and access our web application just in one minute), also client can save URL+key in a file/paper (again this could happen with passwords too!) or leaks it somehow, like in screenshots or so...

If this is a good solution, how can we get higher security?
We are thinking of:

1. Using SSL
2. Using a long random key (256bit / 32 binary bytes / 64 hex characters) from /dev/urandom
3. Disable browser/proxy cache by HTTP headers
4. Disable search engine indexing in whole subdomain
5. Hide key by using `<a href="url+key">LOGIN</a>`, and redirect client to a page like URL/panel to avoid screen shot issues.
6. You say, please?

Comment: A discussion you may find of interest: http://serverfault.com/questions/403771/is-it-okay-to-use-random-urls-instead-of-passwords

Answer (score 1):

My take on it is that if your key is truly random and validated at the back-end, then you shouldn't have any issues. Https might be good for the info submitted during the process AFTER the login verification but yeah... if large enough and truly random (say, seeded using the username or password or email for verification so that you can reproduce the key programmatically at the server end to verify the match), you're very secure.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So you are saying that we play that scenario that I said, and when clients clicks on the login link (URL+Key), we ask for email and verify with email+key that is saved on database, right? So this way email works as username and our random key works as password, it's a very good idea because attacker can't get into system without knowing email. Can you please explain about seeding key with username? Isn't `/dev/urandom` random enough?

Comment: I got what you're saying now. But, I prefer to go with bcrypt instead of SHA-256. Thank you again :)